# Is there an API to access iOS App Store data?

Tags: ios, app-store

I am currently working on a school project and was wondering if there is an API to fetch data such as the current official top ten games from the iOS app store? I know there are websites like sensor tower where I could maybe extract data from, but I was hoping to find an API that accesses the apple store data directly rather than going through a 3rd party website. So far I've not had much luck!

Does anyone have any ideas?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Apple didn't launch any official APIs for accessing the App Store data.

Find below the APIs that are available right now,

1- iTunes Search API, It is for iTunes Store and Apple Books Store.

> https://affiliate.itunes.apple.com/resources/documentation/itunes-store-web-service-search-api/

2- App Store Connect API, It's concerning with apps that added to App Store Connect only.

> https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appstoreconnectapi/testflight/apps

And Check the following similar question as well,

> https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/347123/appstore-api-for-search-and-download

Comment: Thanks for the info. I was aware of the iTunes search api, however that doesn't allow me to search for games or apps unfortunately. The App Store Connect API looks to only allow you to get data on your own games that you've uploaded through app store connect, I don't see how I could use that to get the top ten ranking games?

Comment: Yes, I have wrote at first "Apple didn't launch any official APIs for accessing the App Store data.". Unfortunately, you can't get this officially.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you define "Top Games", for example:

- by downloads?
- by position on Top Charts?
- by average ratings and/or number of ratings?
- and in what countries or categories?

The easiest way would be to use a third-party API that pre-packages all those insights, for example you could use this [Advanced Query API](https://42matters.com/docs/app-market-data/ios/apps/advanced-query-api?utm_source=stackoverflow.com&utm_medium=Referral&utm_campaign=so_a) to search for "games only" and sort by "position on Top Charts". You find several examples in the section "Example Queries".

As you might notice, that endpoint expects a POST request, so make sure you enclose your payload (e.g. JSON-formatted search parameters) in the body of the request message. If you use PHP this other post gives you a good example on how to do it: [How do I send a POST request with PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5647461/how-do-i-send-a-post-request-with-php)

Hope this was helpful! If you have any questions, feel free to get in touch.

(Disclaimer: I am the CEO and co-founder of 42matters.)

Comment: one question, is there any way to get the discovery suggestions in the App Store app with your API?

Comment: @wazowski unfortunately we don't have an API for the discovery suggestions on the App Store at the moment.

Answer (score -2):

The best API for accessing Android and iTunes App Store data is https://www.appmonsta.com. They were recently acquired by [MightySignal](https://mightysignal.com).